# An Element in a C$^{*}$-algebra that is Almost a Projection is Close to a Projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C$^{*}$-algebra and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. I am trying to solve the following problem (Exercise 2.7. in Rordam's little blue book):

> Show that there exists a $\delta>0$ with the following property: If $a\in A$ and $\|a-a^{*}\|\leq\delta$ and $\|a-a^{2}\|\leq \delta$, then there is a projection $p$ such that $\|a-p\|\leq \epsilon$.

Following the hint, we assume that $\epsilon <1/2$ and set $b=\frac{a+a^{*}}{2}$. Then, it is not hard to see that $\sigma(b)\subset[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\cup[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$ provided that $\|b-b^{2}\|\leq\epsilon-\epsilon^{2}$. The hint suggests to put $p:= f(b)$ for some continuous function $f$. Since we are assuming $\epsilon<1/2$, $\sigma(b)$ is disconnected, so I was thinking to make $f$ identically $0$ on $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and identically $1$ on $[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$ or vice-versa. Then, by the Spectral Mapping Theorem, $p$ would be a projection. However, I'm not sure how to conclude that $\|a-p\|\leq \epsilon$, or if this is even the correct choice of $p$.

Also, presumably the fact that $\|b-b^{2}\|\leq\epsilon-\epsilon^{2}$, which we make use of follows from our choice of $\delta$ and the definition of $b$. However, in proving this, I came up with a $\delta$ in terms of $a$, but the way the question is asked suggests that the same $\delta$ should hold for all $a$ satisfying $\|a-a^{*}\|,\|a-a^{2}\|\leq\delta$. Is it possible to choose the $\delta$ independent of $a$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer, but I think you should use the fact that the C*-algebra generated by $b$ is isomorphic via functional calculus with $C(\sigma(b))$.

Comment: I cannot show that $\sigma(b)\subset[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\cup[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality $\|a-p\|<\epsilon$ is simply $|x-f(x)|<\epsilon$ on $\sigma(b)$, i.e., $\|\text{id}-f\|<\epsilon$.

As for the estimate: I assume that what you did is that if $\|a-a^*\|\leq\delta$ and $\|a-a^2\|\leq \delta$, then 
\begin{align}
\|b-b^2\|&=\left\|\frac{a+a^*}2-\left(\frac{a+a^*}2\right)^2\right\|\\ \ \\
&=\frac14\left\|{a-a^2}+\left({a-a^2} \right)^*+(a-aa^*)+(a^*-a^*a) \right\|\\ \ \\
&=\frac14\left\|{a-a^2}+\left({a-a^2} \right)^*+(a-a^2)+a(a-a^*)+(a-a^2)^*+a^*(a^*-a) \right\|\\ \ \\
&\leq \|a-a^2\|+\frac12\,\|a\|\,\|a-a^*\|\leq  \delta\,\left(1+\frac{\|a\|}2\right).
\end{align}
Now, since $b=b^*$, by computations you already made, $$\|b\|\leq\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\delta\,\left(1+\frac{\|a\|}2\right)}.$$ As $b$ is the real part of $a$, and $$\|\text{Im}(a)\|=\frac12\,\|a-a^*\|\leq\delta,$$
we have
$$
\|a\|\leq\|b\|+\frac\delta2\leq\frac{\delta+1}2+\sqrt{\frac14+\delta\,\left(1+\frac{\|a\|}2\right)}.
$$
We can rewrite this as 
$$
\|a\|^2-\left(\frac\delta2+1\right)\|a\|-\frac14-\delta+\left(\frac{\delta+1}2\right)^2\leq0.
$$
Then, analyzing the quadratic (i.e., trusting Wolfram Alpha),
$$
\|a\|\leq\frac14\,\left(2+3\delta+\sqrt{4+20\delta+5\delta^2}\right).
$$

Comment: But $aa^* \neq a^*a$.

Comment: Of course. If $a $ is normal, none of this is needed.

Comment: I mean that $(a+a^*)^2\neq a^2+2aa^*+(a^*)^2$ in the above equality

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I think it's just a typo,  I'll correct it a little later today.

Comment: Done. $\ \ \ \ $

Comment: So $p=f(b)$ is the spectral projection onto $[1/2,3/2]$ of $b$ correct? If so could you provide more details on why $\|a-p\|<1/2$?

Comment: I can't seem to see why $||a-p|| = ||b-p||$. Would you be able to briefly explain why? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: It won't be true when $a$ is not selfadjoint. My previous comment was wrong (and unnecessary).

Comment: What happens with $\varepsilon$ is simply that for $\varepsilon\geq1/2$ one replaces it with $\varepsilon'<1/2$. Any $\delta$ that works for $\varepsilon'$ will work for $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I understand that part. I can see that $||b-p|| \leq \epsilon$ (as with the previous argument) but I am still failing to see how to get $||a-p|| \leq \epsilon$. Do you know how to get this?

Comment: $\|a-p\|<\varepsilon$ is the original inequality where the argument starts.

Answer (score 0):

Take  $0<\epsilon <\frac{1}{2}$.
Say $\delta>0 $ is such that $\delta + \frac{\delta^2}{4} = \epsilon - \epsilon^2 $.

Then for $a \in A$,  $\|a^*-a\|\le\delta$, $\|a^2-a\|\le\delta$ we choose,   $b=\frac{a+a^*}{2}$
\begin{align}
\|b-b^2\| = \frac{1}{4}\|2a+2a^*-a^2-(a^*)^2-aa^*-a^*a\|=\frac{1}{4}\|a-a^2+a^*-(a^*)^2+a-a^2+a^*-(a^*)^2+(a-a^*)^2\|\le \|a-a^2\|+\frac{1}{4}\|(a-a^*)^2\|\le \delta + \frac{\delta^2}{4} =\epsilon -\epsilon^2
\end{align}
So, we have $b=b^*$ i.e. $\sigma(b)\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Next our claim is $\sigma(b)\subset[-\epsilon,\epsilon] \cup [1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$

For this let $\lambda \in \sigma(b)$ so, $\lambda -\lambda^2\in\sigma(b-b^2)$ i.e. $|\lambda-\lambda^2|\le\|b-b^2\|\le\epsilon-\epsilon^2$ i.e. $-\epsilon+\epsilon^2\le\lambda-\lambda^2\le\epsilon-\epsilon^2$

So, from $\lambda-\lambda^2\le\epsilon-\epsilon^2$ we get $\lambda\ge1-\epsilon \:or\:\lambda\le\epsilon $

from $\lambda-\lambda^2\ge\epsilon^2-\epsilon\:$ i.e. $\:\lambda-\lambda^2\ge-\epsilon^2-\epsilon\:$ we have $\lambda\ge-\epsilon\:or\:\lambda\le1+\epsilon\:$ so, our claim is proved.

Now, as $b$ is self adjoint so using continuous functional calculus we have,

$\phi: C(\sigma(b))\:\longrightarrow\: C^*({b,1})$ is $*$-isometric isomorphism.

Define $f \in C(\sigma(b))$ by $f\:$= characteristic function on $\sigma(b)\:\cap\:[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$

So, $\phi(f)=f(b)$ gives,

$\phi(f)^*=f(b)^*\:or\:\phi(\bar{f})=f(b)^* \:or\:\phi(f)=f(b)^* \:or\: f(b)=f(b)^*$

again, $\phi(f)^2=f(b)^2\:or\:\phi(f^2)=f(b)^2\:or\:\phi(f)=f(b)^2\:or\:f(b)=f(b)^2$

i.e. $f(b)$ is a projection in $A$.

Now,
\begin{align}
\|a-f(b)\|\le\|a-b\|+\|b-f(b)\|=\frac{1}{2}\|a-a^*\|+\|b-f(b)\|\le\frac{\delta}{2}+\|\phi(I-f)\| \: (where\:I=identity function \: on \:\sigma(b)) = \frac{\delta}{2} + \|I-f\| (as\:\phi\: is \:isometry) \le \frac{\delta}{2} + Sup{|z-f(z)|}\: (where \:supremum \:is \:taken\: on \:\sigma(b)\: \cap\:([-\epsilon,\epsilon] \: \cup\: [1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]))\:\le\frac{\delta}{2}+\epsilon = \frac{3\epsilon-\epsilon^2}{2}
\end{align}

So, for $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$ we can choose a $\delta\ge0$
with the following property: If $a\in A$
and $\|a−a^*\|\le\delta$
and $\|a−a^2\|\le\delta$
, then there is a projection p
such that $\|a−p\|≤\frac{3\epsilon-\epsilon^2}{2}$. By arbitrariness of $\epsilon$ we get our result.